# Amazon Alexa and Multi-Room Music Groups

Tags: smart-home, amazon-echo

I have a Show and a Dot set up across an apartment from one another and I have them connected for the Multi-Room Music Group feature. Now, however, while I (of course) want to maintain the group they are in together, I nonetheless want to listen to the Show without the Dot also playing. But I can't figure out how to disengage the Group.

Basically, I was listening to them both synced together, now I'm done doing that, but can't figure out how to stop the second device from playing without explicitly removing it from the Group, which I would prefer remain intact for the next time I want them both playing in sync.

Any thoughts or ideas are greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have shared your question on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/alexa/comments/7lhwfm/amazon_alexa_and_multiroom_music_groups/), check out what they have advised.

Answer (score 4):

Just say Alexa - Stop everywhere.  Nothing has to be playing to say it.

When you say stop everywhere, it stops the everywhere group. The next time you start something it will only be on one device. If it is already playing on multiple devices, it will stop what is playing then you can start it again, and when you do it will only play on one device

Comment: That doesn't answer the question since the OP does want the show to keep playing.

Comment: When you say stop everywhere, it stops the everywhere group.  The next time you start something it will only be on one device.  If it is already playing on multiple devices, it will stop what is playing then you can start it again, and when you do it will only play on one device.

Comment: Please include that into your answer via [edit] and optimally include a source that backs this up. Currently it's a bit thin.

Comment: I'll throw it into an edit -- new to this site.  I just tested it on my own echo dots, would me taking a video of it work as a source?